# one view to another view in my code

Tags: asp.net-core

This is my controller

```cs
public IActionResult Index(Product p)
{
    ProductDAL pd = new ProductDAL();
    pd.Insert(p);
    return View(p);
}

public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

This is my model Product.cs

```cs
namespace AWaaS.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Required]
        public int BaseSiteApllicationNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Create view page

```html
<form asp-controller="Replica" asp-action="Index" method="post">
<label asp-for="BaseSiteApllicationNumber">BaseSiteApllicationNumber</label>
<input asp-for="BaseSiteApllicationNumber" class="form-control" />
```

here it is my index view page

```html
@model AWaaS.Models.Product

<div>BaseSiteApllicationNumber:@Model.BaseSiteApllicationNumber</div>
```

I want to insert some value in my  Create view page and it will store in SQL server

```cs
public void Insert(Product p)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=.; Initial catalog=xxxx;Integrated security=true");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Replica_Request(BaseSiteApllicationNumber)values(@BaseSiteApllicationNumber),con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaseSiteApllicationNumber", p.BaseSiteApllicationNumber);
}
```

but it is not redirected from creating page to Index page

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to index page after create action, you need to return to index action. So, your create action should return like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

or

```
return View("Index");
```

or

```
return Redirect("Home/Index");
```

Comment: it does not work.please send your email adress i will send my code.